# How we should use 'it's not worth it' structure for an activity

Tags: grammar

**How should I use this structure to convey the matter in my question exactly like a native:**

> **1.** It is not worth it we are moving next year 
>   **2.** It is not worth it if we move next year 
>   **3.** It is not worth it moving next year for us 
>   **4.** It is not worth moving next year for us

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are even trying to say. The first two make it sound like something isn't worth doing _because_ we are moving next year: "Should we repaint the house this summer?" "No, it's not worth it – we are moving next year." The second two make it sound like it's not worth moving: "Do you think we should move to the city next year?" "No, for us, it won't be worth moving next year. We should just stay here." ***What are you trying to say?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Moving next year is not worth it for us.

For us, moving next year is not worth it.
```

You can say "isn't" instead of "is not" because this sentence is conversational.

EDIT
As J.R. said, it depends on what you're trying to say.

If your context is akin to *It makes no sense to move next year, to take a low-paying part-time teaching position in that (far-off) city, because we'd simply have to move back here the following year so I can finish my degree, and the combined moving expenses would be greater than my salary!* then you could say

**It isn't worth it for us to move next year.**

But if you mean something like  *We shouldn't spend money on an annual health club membership because we're moving in January to another city.* then you could say:

**Getting an annual health club membership isn't worth it; we're moving next year.**

And with respect to your comment, what about *It's not worth it we move next year*

if you mean to ask about the verb tense, then yes, the present tense can be used to indicate the future:

**It's not worth it -- we move next year.**

Comment: Thanks. And what about this one:
"It's not worth it we move next year."

Comment: @A-friend - Try: "It's not worth it because we are moving next year."

Comment: @A-friend. See my additional comments.

Comment: @TRomano you intelligently got my point and answered me in the way one should have done it. Thank you very much for the concern.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) It is not worth it; we are moving next year. (add a semi-colon as there is no conjunction)
>   2) It **will not be** worth it if we move next year. (fix mixed tenses)

3) and 4) I think it is better to avoid using "for us", unless you are specifically trying to be indirect.